# What to do to bring an old question up in front again and not able to Set up bounty on question?

Tags: support, edits, bounty

I am having an old question which was not clear earlier due to my lack of knowledge about the topic. But recently I have worked on that topic and gained a little bit of knowledge about it. So what should I do to get up in front again, as I've edited it and there's no option for bounty as well?

[image]

As you can see in the image, I'm not able to set a bounty.

Comment: You've already [accepted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38419370/3001761), why do you need more input?

Comment: The answer is from me only and I wanted if anyone else can provide more info. about the question.

Comment: If you want more information, though, *why have you accepted it?*

Comment: I don't think I've asked this for a particular question. I'm just trying to learn the ways here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have edited it, it will *automatically* be bumped to the front page. You don't need to do anything else. If you edit to provide new information to the question: perfect. You *shouldn't* edit a question just for the sake of bumping.

If you still don't get a satisfactory answer, you could consider putting a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on it to draw more attention. Because you answered the question yourself, your bounty must be at least [100 points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). That's why you can't start a bounty at the moment - you don't have the required 100 reputation.

Comment: I thought it was 50 minimum points earlier.Has it changed as earlier I had the power to to set up a bounty.

Comment: No, this hasn't changed. You're not able to put a bounty on it because you posted an answer. You *should* be able to put a bounty on your other questions.